# Encrypt WCF messages without authentication from the client

Tags: wcf, authentication, encryption

i want to encrypt messages in a WCF scenario where the binding is tcp.NetBinding and the security is bound on transport.

I found out, that if i dont encrypt the messages, i dont have to make client credentialhandling between client and server.
But if i want to encryt, it seems that there has to be some kind of 
client-authentication (Windows credentials, Certificate ...).

The WCF server wont start with credentials are set to Null and encryption is on.
Is it possible to encrypt messages between the client and the server without authenticating the client?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the scenario is called [Transport Security with an Anonymous Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729789(v=vs.110).aspx):

> This Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) scenario uses transport
>   security (HTTPS) to ensure confidentiality and integrity. The server
>   must be authenticated with a Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) certificate,
>   and the clients must trust the server's certificate. The client is not
>   authenticated by any mechanism and is, therefore, anonymous.

The bare bones binding is setup as follows:

```
var binding = new NetTcpBinding();
binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Transport;
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.None;
```

Also in this particular scenario, the security is provided by **TLS over TCP** to ensure confidentiality and integrity. Again all that is required is to have the client trust the certificate provided by the server. The client is not authenticated by the server and is therefore known as an **anonymous client**.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i will try it with netTcp binding :)

Comment: I have edited my answer to include the `NetTcpBinding` setup instead of the one for `WSHttpBinding`.

Comment: Have you had any issue adopting this approach?

Comment: Thx a lot man. i had some more issues, but now it works with my own certificate and cross-machine with anonymous Client :D